# Google maps GPS: longitude and latitude returns zero

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, location

I need to get location or latitude longitude from Main class, but it returns null if i get location or 0.0 if i get latitude and longitude as in this code below. Tried to minimize code and make it clear as it is possible.

here is the service class where i need to get the location from main class

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);

        if(MainActivity.isMarkerDragged()) {

            Location markerLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            markerLocation.setLatitude(MainActivity.getMarkerLat());
            markerLocation.setLongitude(MainActivity.getMarkerLon());

            Toast.makeText(mContext, MainActivity.getMarkerLon() + " = " + MainActivity.getMarkerLat(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Current location
            distance = location.distanceTo(markerLocation);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "marker dragged " + distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

On method onLocationChanged i am getting this longitude and lattitude

```
endPoint.setTitle(endPoint.getPosition().longitude + ", " + endPoint.getPosition().latitude);
```

This works as planned but when i get the position on service it returns 0.0 (sucks)

```
public static Marker endPoint;
public static boolean markerDragged = true;
public static boolean serviceStarted = false;

private static double markerLat;
private static double markerLon;

/**
 * Gets the current location of the device, and positions the map's camera.
 */
private void getDeviceLocation() {
    /*
     * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
     * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
     * onRequestPermissionsResult.
     */
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    /*
     * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
     * cases when a location is not available.
     */
    if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
        mLastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
    if (mCameraPosition != null) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));
    } else if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                        mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));

        // Adding a marker
        endPoint = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .draggable(true)
                .position(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                        mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude())));
        endPoint.setTitle(getString(R.string.drag));
    } else {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    }
}
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    if(!serviceStarted) {
        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    }
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    setMarkerDragged(true);

    markerLat = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    markerLon = marker.getPosition().longitude;

    endPoint.setTitle(endPoint.getPosition().longitude + ", " + endPoint.getPosition().latitude);
}

public static double getMarkerLon(){
    return markerLon;
}

public static double getMarkerLat(){
    return markerLat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: on Main class:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        intent.putExtra("latitude", endPoint.getPosition().latitude);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", endPoint.getPosition().longitude);
        startService(intent);
```

and on Service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    markerLat = (Double) intent.getExtras().get("latitude");
    markerLon = (Double) intent.getExtras().get("longitude");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```